# Alternative to fetch join with "ON clause" in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Given is the following domain model in a RDBMS that is mapped with Hibernate into Java objects.

```
┌─────────┐            ┌─────────────┐
│ Project │ 1     0..n │ UserSetting │
├─────────┼------------┼─────────────┤
│  name   │            │   username  │
└─────────┘            │   favorite  │
                       └─────────────┘
```

Users can flag a project as favorite which is reflected by an associated (optional) `UserSetting` entry.
If a user did not flag a project, there is **no `UserSetting` entry** in the database which implies that the project is no favorite. Think of `UserSetting` being "sparse".

Furthermore given: Entities should be fetched via JPA with Hibernate as provider.

Assume that the `Project` and the `UserSetting` table can be very large. Optimizing the database schema should not be subject to this question. Assume that efficient indexes exist.

For a given user I would like to efficiently fetch all projects including the favorite status for that particular user. Note the sort criterium!

My initial approach was to formulate the following JPQL query:

```
SELECT p, us FROM Project p
    LEFT JOIN FETCH UserSetting us
    WHERE us.username IS NULL OR us.username = :currentUser
    ORDER BY COALESCE(us.favorite, false) DESC, p.name ASC
```

This does not work if `currentUser` does **not** have a `UserSetting` but `userB` has. The `UserSetting` of `userB` will be joined but the project will not be listed due to the `WHERE` clause.

Fortunately, [JPA 2.1 introduces JOINS with ON clause](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367452) ([Javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Join.html#on(javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate...))) which can be used to reformulate the query into:

```
SELECT p, us FROM Project p
    LEFT JOIN FETCH UserSetting us
    ON us.username IS NULL OR us.username = :currentUser
    ORDER BY COALESCE(us.favorite, false) DESC, p.name ASC
```

Unfortunately, Hibernate (4.3.6) does not support fetch joins with "*ON clause*" ("*WITH clause*" in Hibernate's lingus) and quits with the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters
```

How could the query be reformulated in order to implement the functionality and fulfill my constraints:

- Fixed domain model
- Efficient query that scales well
- JPA + Hibernate
- Hibernate specific features should be avoided

Comment: Same with hibernate 5 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More recent discovery is that the [JPA 2.1 (JSR 338)](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338) specification defines the grammar without allowing "ON clauses" for fetch joins.

My workaround is to omit the object mapping feature of Hibernate and explicitly selecting the required fields of `Project` and `UserSetting`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following to also retrieve Project without UserSettings:

```
SELECT p, us FROM Project p
LEFT JOIN FETCH UserSetting us
WHERE us is null OR us.username IS NULL OR us.username = :currentUser
ORDER BY COALESCE(us.favorite, false) DESC, p.name ASC
```

The

```
 us is null
```

part in the WHERE clause of the query does the trick.